# Zsh gives "permission denied" error on iTerm2

Tags: macos, permissions, zsh, iterm2

I configured my zsh by downloading the latest using homebrew on Yosemite. So the default shell is `/usr/local/bin/zsh` on iTerm2 application.

However, when I try the command

```
$ ..  
$ zsh: permission denied: ..
```

It doesn't output the directory contents as it is supposed to. Can I also try other features to verify if zsh shell is configured correctly?

Comment: `..` is a directory, which you cannot execute. You need `cd ..` (if that's what you mean to do).

Comment: @AFH Zsh has an `autocd` option which `cd`s to a directory if you type its name. Of course, just typing `..` should not output the directory contents either. Shah, can you please clarify? What happens when you run `ls ..` or `cd ..`?

Comment: @slhck - It looks like `autocd` isn't enabled on the questioner's shell, as it isn't on mine. He needs to add `setopt autocd` to `~/.zshrc`. As you say, that won't display the contents. The contents (at least the directories and executables) will be shown as completion options if he types `../` then the _Tab_ key: maybe it is this he was thinking of, and it is unaffected by setting `autocd`.

Comment: The `..` feature is mentioned in the video _Learning & Discovering ZSH Features - Command Line Power User (7/11)_ on youtube as enabled but the castor has also installed oh-my-zsh. I think it must be a zsh shell feature.  
`ls ..` and `cd ..` commands perform as expected: listing contents of the directory above and navigating to above directory respectively.  
The ../ then _Tab_ key works for me while no `setopt autocd` is in my `~/.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```sh
setopt autocd
```

to your `~/.zshrc` file to be able to change dirs this way. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTOCD for more info.